# Is there a way to parameterize a jquery function name and call it?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a plugin for a modal and I want the users to be able to initialize the animate function picking from a jquery list of functions like fadeIn , SlideDown etc.

```
var myModal = new createModal({
    content: myContent,
   appendTo: ".modalSection"
});

$(".modal_trigger").on("click", function () {
   myModal.open();
});

createModal.prototype.open = function () {
    var functionVar = this.options.animateType;
    $(this.modal).fadeIn();
    //i want to replace this above line with the function name in this.options.animateType
}
```

Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a jQuery object is, as the name implies, an object, you can access its properties as you would any standard object.

In this case you can use bracket notation to call a function held in one of those properties. For example:

```
createModal.prototype.open = function () {
  var functionVar = this.options.animateType;
  $(this.modal)[functionVar]();
}
```

Comment: I was trying this.modal.__proto__[functionVar]() , I kept getting back a function definition, your answer works well. Thank you.